# Win and Mac installers from Win

Tags: air, cross-platform

Is it possible to create installers for both Windows and Mac from Windows?

Will the *.air file and/or the *.fla be read in Mac if created in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

.air installers will work on any desktop platform that has AIR installed (AIR is supported for sure on Mac and Windows). So you can create on one platform and run on all. The FLA is your project file and is not actually your application.

You can also create an exe installer using Windows or a .app file using OS X. These do not require that AIR be installed, I believe. However, you may not create an exe on OS X or a .app on Windows.